# Thymeleaf put a dynamic parameter inside script tag

Tags: thymeleaf

With thymeleaf and following code

```
<script th:src="@{/js/init.js}"></script>
```

I would like to make it like following in order to avoid browser caching for this file

```
<script th:src="@{/js/init.js?${minute}}"></script>
```

${minute} will be current time minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```xml
<script th:src="@{/js/init.js(minute=${minute})}"></script>
```

Reference: [Standard URL Syntax](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

I solve the question by use the following, it's a bit longer than expected.

```
<script th:src="@{/js/init.js(minute=${#dates.format(#dates.createNow(), 'mm')})}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to provide versioned static files, you might try spring resource versioning. One possible solution using configuration only is described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49040930.