# Spring MVC and Thymeleaf Resource Versioning

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, caching, thymeleaf

[image: Resource Hierarchy My Project]

I am trying resource versioning with Spring Mvc 4.I use thymeleaf template engine.But doesnt work with the following code.When load the page I cant see new version Url when i view the page source. So what's the problem in my code? What do I miss?

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/theme*//**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/theme/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS))
            .resourceChain(false)
            .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
            .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformer());
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static*//**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS))
            .resourceChain(false)
            .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
            .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformer());
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/js*//**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/js/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS))
            .resourceChain(false)
            .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
            .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformer());
}

@Bean
public ResourceUrlEncodingFilter resourceUrlEncodingFilter() {
    return new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter();
}
```

I am using with expression in script tag.
**th:src="@{/resources/static/js/companyList.js}"**

Comment: I have very similar non-working code; for me it's not setting the cache control headers suggesting that it's not using the handler. Is your version setting the headers for 365 days?

Comment: My problem is related resource path.Incorrectly created url cause the problem.When you view the source of page can you see versioning url with md5?If you see problem is still continue? My problem is solved and now i can see cache headers for 365 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the my solution.I debug source code of Spring.ServletContextResource class create a relativeRelative.Then check whether resource is exists.

Resource location : /resources/static/

Path : /static/css/login.css

pathToUse : /resources/static/static/css/login.css --> this resource url not exists so return null.

**ServletContextResource class**

```
@Override
public Resource createRelative(String relativePath) {
    String pathToUse = StringUtils.applyRelativePath(this.path, relativePath);
    return new ServletContextResource(this.servletContext, pathToUse);
}
```

**Solution:**
Resource location : /resources/static/

Path : /css/login.css

pathToUse : /resources/static/css/login.css

Now I include this format.Remove /resources from path.

**th:src="@{/css/login.css}"**

```
           @Override
           public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) 
           {

                registry.addResourceHandler("/theme*//**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/")
                        .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS))
                        .resourceChain(false)
                        .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
                        .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformer());
                registry.addResourceHandler("/css*//**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/")
                        .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS))
                        .resourceChain(false)
                        .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
                        .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformer());
                registry.addResourceHandler("/js*//**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/")
                        .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS))
                        .resourceChain(false)
                        .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"))
                        .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformer());

         @Override
         public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
 web.ignoring().antMatchers("/theme/**").antMatchers("/js/**").antMatchers("/css/**");
            }
```

Answer (score 12):

I managed it with no code, only config in application.properties:

```
# Enable HTML5 application cache manifest rewriting.
spring.resources.chain.html-application-cache=true

# Enable the Spring Resource Handling chain. Disabled by default unless at least one strategy has been enabled.
spring.resources.chain.enabled=true
# Enable the content Version Strategy.
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
# Comma-separated list of patterns to apply to the Version Strategy.
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
```

I didn't need to add any other code to get the hash version in the URLs for CSS and JS.

Comment: It would be even more awesome if you pointed us to the documentation for this

Comment: Good suggestion, completely agree. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ResourceProperties.java ? That's about all I can find, useful as reference but doesn't explain what each setting really does or how to combine them.

Comment: Be sure to use `th:href="@{/css/app.css}"` and not just `href` so that Thymeleaf can put the correct path in the href link.

Answer (score 7):

**1.** Create Thymeleaf `LinkBuilder` that uses Spring's `ResourceUrlProvider` to create versioned links:

```
@Configuration
public class TemplateEngineConfig {
    @Autowired
    public void configureTemplateEngine(SpringTemplateEngine engine,
                                        ResourceUrlProvider urlProvider) {
        engine.setLinkBuilder(new VersioningLinkBuilder(urlProvider));
    }
}

class VersioningLinkBuilder extends StandardLinkBuilder {
    private final ResourceUrlProvider urlProvider;

    VersioningLinkBuilder(ResourceUrlProvider urlProvider) {
        this.urlProvider = urlProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public String processLink(IExpressionContext context, String link) {
        String lookedUpLink = urlProvider.getForLookupPath(link);
        if (lookedUpLink != null) {
            return super.processLink(context, lookedUpLink);
        } else {
            return super.processLink(context, link);
        }
    }
}
```

**2.** Use thymeleaf tags `th:href` and `th:src`

```
<link th:href="@{/main.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script th:src="@{/js/main.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It will be converted to:

```
<link href="/main-0c362e5c8643b75ddf64940262b219f7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/js/main-c13acb86fa1012e27bbb01a7c4a9bf7f.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**3.**(Optional) It is also recommended to add browser cache headers. Add to your `application.properties`:

```
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.max-age=365d
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-cache=false
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-store=false
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.cache-public=true
```

Or if you use `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  resources:
    chain:
      strategy:
        content:
          enabled: true
          paths: /**
    cache:
      cachecontrol:
        max-age: 365d
        no-cache: false
        no-store: false
        cache-public: true
```

Comment: I deployed my app under context, so during link processing I had to remove and lately append the context path. Here is the idea:
if (linkToProcess.startsWith(servletContext.getContextPath()){...}
...
return super.processLink(context, servletContext.getContextPath() + linkToProcess);

Comment: This is what worked for me on Spring Boot 2.4, thanks for the writeup!

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

**application.yml**

```
...
resources:
  chain:
    strategy:
      content:
        enabled: true
        paths: /js/**,/css/**
...
```

**index.html**

```
...
<script th:src=@{/js/home.js}></script>
...
```

**Result**

This renders something like this:

```
...
<script src=/js/home-440273f30b71d3cf4184b48ce5e10b94.js></script>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage of ResourceUrlEncodingFilter filters all urls in the page, which is not desirable and causes performance issues. My solution is the following:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/javascript/*.js", "/css/*.css", "/img/*")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/javascript/", "classpath:/static/css/", "classpath:/static/img/")
                    .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(365, TimeUnit.DAYS))
                    .resourceChain(true)
                    .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"));
```

and inside the page using the below function to lookup the static resource

```
<script th:src="${@mvcResourceUrlProvider.getForLookupPath('/javascript/app.js')}"></script>
```